Run MSTest integration tests from inside c# project
what would be the best way to run all tests from MSTest project from within my c# app? I know that it may be silly idea but I would like to have an option to run all test cases using API call to my webAPI project. Thanks!

I doubt there's any existing library for that. You'd need to build your own test-runner for that.

Deploy the test code with the project add an endpoint that properly calls "dotnet  test" for the deployed test projects and then somehow create a returnable result of those runs. The more detail you want to return here the more effort is presumably in that step. And maybe you need an async endpoint when the tests are extensive and long running you will get into http timeout problems. For "dotnet test" to work you need to deploy the SDK of the Net core framework version you use.
